# Triple bond using mhchem in beamer

Tags: beamer, mhchem

I need to write chemical mechanisms in presentations. Using `mhchem` is a quick and easy solution to write presentable chemical equations however the triple bond command (`#` or `\bond{#}`) produces error messages even though it produces the desired output.

Though I can use `chemfig` package to do all I want.

Is it possible to still use `mhchem` and get no error message?

My MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Triple Bond}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \ce{H-C#C-H + HX -> H2C=CH+ + X-}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Error message visible on TexStudio (using TeX-Live-2017)

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate. \end{frame}
Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate. \end{frame}
Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@doifinframe. \end{frame}
```

Output ::
[image]

Comment: your problem is the document class "beamer", if you change it to "article" no errors occur.
Class "beamer" must not support "mhchem"

Comment: As far as I have explored, this is the only problem using ``mhchem`` with ``beamer``. Changing to ``article`` serves no purpose as I want this to be a presentation and I do not want to format everything about a document.

Comment: You can use "chemformula", it is supported by "beaner" class.

Answer (score 3):

Add option **fragile** to frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Triple Bond}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \ce{H-C#C-H + HX -> H2C=CH+ + X-}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

beamer seems to choke on `#`. You can use **\bond{3}** instead.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Triple Bond}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \ce{H-C\bond{3}C-H + HX -> H2C=CH+ + X-}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the document class "beamer", if you change it to "article" no errors occur. Class "beamer" must not support "mhchem".
But "chemfig" is supported.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
    \chemfig{H-C~C-H} 
    \+ 
    \chemfig{HX} 
    \arrow{->} 
    \chemfig{H_2C=CH^+} 
    \+ 
    \chemfig{X^{-}}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

OR you can use "chemformula"

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
    
    \ch{H-C+C-H + HX -> H2C=CH+ + X-}
    

\end{document}
```